# PHP - Getting a small part of a string within a string, criteria-based

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I need to be able to search within a string and find out if [topic] is equal to a number and grab that number only from within the string.

For example, a string like so:

```
[topic]=10[board]=1
```

should return 10

But a string like this:

```
[topic][board]=1
```

should return 0 or false

A string like this:

```
[topic]=1.5[board]=2
```

should return 1, cause we need to round down `floor()`

Also, we aren't worried about negative numbers, cause this will never happen.

How can I do this to just grab the number only, rounding down, from these types of strings that look like this, only if `[topic]` is present in the string and defined with an equal sign.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea below uses [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) and a regular express that looks for the word "topic" inside square brackets followed by an equal sign and one of more numbers. Before the matches, I set the default value of the topic (`false` in this case). If a topic is found, I then convert it to an integer.

This will ignore the decimal point and any numbers that follow as `\d` only contains the numbers 0 through 9.

**Example:**

```
<?php 

$string = '[topic]=10[board]=1';

$topic = false;
if (preg_match('/\[topic\]=(?P<topic>\d+)/', $string, $matches)) {
    $topic = (int)$matches['topic'];
}

var_dump($topic);
```

Comment: Will this work if we have this... `[topic]=35.8` should return 35, and `[topic]=185.0` should return 185.

Comment: Ok, I believe it works, thanks a million for your help with this!